# Can't render the image when setting its url in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, file, server.mappath

When i set the image with an url in code behind it doesn't work , i don't know why ?

```
 if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Images/EmpQr/") + int.Parse(Session["userID"].ToString()) + ".PNG")) //It passes this condition 
            {
                tr_res.Visible = true;
                img_res.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath("~/Images/EmpQr/" + int.Parse(Session["userID"].ToString()) + ".PNG"); //Here 's the problem ,no image 

            }
            else
            {
                tr_res.Visible = false;
            }
```

---

```
<asp:Image ID="img_res" runat="server" AlternateText="result"  />
```

When i set image url like this

```
ImageUrl ="~/Images/EmpQr/1345.PNG"
```

in the design view it works .

How to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Server.MapPath` gives you local path to the file. While what you really want is the relative to the application root path (on the server!). For this what you already have, `~/Images/EmpQr/` is fine, so just append file name to it:

```
img_res.ImageUrl = string.Format("{0}{1}.PNG", "~/Images/EmpQr/", int.Parse(Session["userID"].ToString()));
```

**Update.** Out of curiosity, after discussion in comments, here is the relevant part of `Image` control source code, which proves that url in form of `~/Images/...` will be handled correctly:

```
protected override void AddAttributesToRender(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
base.AddAttributesToRender(writer);
string text = this.ImageUrl;
if (!this.UrlResolved)
{
    text = base.ResolveClientUrl(text);
}
if (this.RenderingCompatibility >= VersionUtil.Framework45)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) || base.DesignMode)
    {
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Src, text);
    }
}
else
{
    if (text.Length > 0 || !base.EnableLegacyRendering)
    {
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Src, text);
    }
}
    //...
```

Comment: @Icarus, actually, it will. Firstly note that OP mentioned that exactly the same URL, specified explicitly in the markpu, works fine. Secondly remember that whatever you are setting as a value of the control (we are talking about `asp:Image` here, not just `img` tag), ASP.NET will process afterwards, and handle the urls appropriately. IN ASP.NET `~/` is a common way to reference app root folder.

Comment: I think you are right. I thought about it afterwards... This is a server control and will likely call ResolveClientUrl behind the scenes.

Comment: @Icarus, it does call this method internally. If you have ILSpy or similar, you can check `Image.AddAttributesToRender` method

Comment: That's what I thought... I am typing from my cell so I can't confirm but will take your word for it ;) can you edit your answer so I can up vote it? The system doesn't let me unless you edit it :-(

Answer (score 3):

You found the problem yourself, because as you say, setting the image URL using "~/Images/.../" works, whereas using Server.MapPath doesn't. The reason Server.MapPath doesn't work is because this function returns the physical path to the image (as in c:\site...) and what you need is the Virtual Path. You can set the Image Path from code behind using Page.ResolveClientUrl instead. Something like this:

```
image.ImageUrl= ResolveClientURL("~/Images/image.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

Server.MapPath("~/Images/EmpQr/" + int.Parse(Session["userID"].ToString()) + ".PNG") instead of this use this one
Server.MapPath("~/Images/EmpQr/") + int.Parse(Session["userID"].ToString()) + ".PNG"

Comment: There are changes in open and close braces. First check then comment.

Comment: I didn't say is was wrong because of the brackets, I said it was wrong because of the way you are setting the image URL. You cannot use Server.MapPath. Your answer is still wrong, sorry.